# Jackson: field types restriction

Tags: java, jackson

Is it possible to make jackson throw an exception on writing json if passed pojo contains a field of unexpected type?
Expected types I would like to provide along with custom serializers.

Comment: How could a type be not expected? You pass a class reference to the mapper which clearly defines all fields.

Comment: @TA I'm talking about fields of pojo passed to ObjectWriter.writeValueAsBytes(Object value). I would like it to fail, if object contains any fields except Strings or Integers for example.

Comment: You wrote write as JSON in your question? That's not the point of an `ObjectMapper` anyway, it will write the object as it is. If you want to check if you are writing the right object check it beforehand, e.g. with `instanceof`

Comment: Set of accepted classes is not predefined. My jackson wrapper should accept any object that meet fields type restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson wraps all properties in `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter` objects and they are responsible for serialisation value. We can decorate these objects with our custom implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonTypeApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule fieldRestrictionModule = new SimpleModule("FieldRestriction");
        fieldRestrictionModule.setSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {
                return beanProperties.stream().map(p -> new PrimitivesOnlyBeanPropertyWriter(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        });

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(fieldRestrictionModule)
                .build();

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Test()));
    }
}

class PrimitivesOnlyBeanPropertyWriter extends BeanPropertyWriter {

    public PrimitivesOnlyBeanPropertyWriter(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        super(writer);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
        if (getType().isPrimitive()) {
            super.serializeAsField(bean, gen, prov);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(getType().getTypeName() + " is not allowed!");
        }
    }
}
```

If `Test` class contains only primitive fields object will be properly serialised. In other case - `java.lang.IllegalStateException` will be thrown.